# How do I gracefully make a java.util.Scanner wait for input again?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following part of a program, which emulates a very basic menu.

```
while (true) {
    int selection;
    try {
        selection = scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        selection = -1;
    }
    switch (selection) {
    case 0:
        System.exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("No valid selection!");
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I enter *not* an integer, the `selection` is set to `-1` and the error message is printed. However, the loop continues endlessly, with the `Scanner` not waiting for any input.

How do I tell it to wait again? How do I fail more gracefully on malformed user input here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `Scanner` fails to read something, the offending data is *not* removed from the stream, which means any subsequent read will fail again until the data is cleared.

To fix this, you could, on failure, just read something and ignore the result:

```
try {
    selection = scanner.nextInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    selection = -1;
    scanner.next(); // discard the input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure throwing and catching an exception is relevant in your case.

Try:

```
boolean isValid = false;
int selection;
while(!isValid) {
    isValid = scanner.hasNextInt();
    if(!isValid) {
        System.out.println("No valid selection!");
        scanner.next();
    } else {
        selection = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
if(selection == 0) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly decent approach, except for your cheesy `isInteger()` method ;) `Integer.parseInt(String i)` does this for you, and throws an exception if it's not an integer. (which is exactly what is happening when using `scanner.nextInt()` ... )

Comment: I know, but `Integer.parseInt` should not be used to test if a String is an int ;-) Anyway one is free to implement that `isInteger` method the way he wants :)

Comment: Java would seem to disagree with you as that's exactly what `Scanner` does. (I personally agree, as does Josh Bloch, that exceptions should only be used for exceptional conditions). The point I was trying to make, however, is that the convention is that if you're expecting an `int`, use `nextInt()` and catch the exception (discarding the token with `next()` in the catch). Even better, you can use `hasNextInt()` avoiding the exception handling entirely. There's simply no reason to write your own implementation of anything here.

Comment: Agreed on the `hasNextInt` method. It actually is more elegant ;)

Answer (score -3):

Make some user input exit out/break the while loop. Like if a user enters "Exit" while loop stops.

Besides that you can do something like:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    selection = -1;
}
switch (selection) {
case 0:
    System.exit(0);
default:
    System.out.println("No valid selection!");
    System.out.println("Try again!");
    selection = scanner.nextInt();        
}
```

Comment: The problem is what @EtiennedeMartel describes in his answer; `nextInt()` does *not* remove the token from the scanner on failure and thus his program goes into a endless loop (as would yours).

Comment: This won't work. If `nextInt()` failed, then any call to `nextInt()` will fail again until the data is removed from the stream.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work and just throws a subsequent Exception.